# python switch statement doesn't work

Tags: python, file-io, switch-statement

I have found a function which implement a switch statement -->

```
File = open('/file.txt','r')

    String = File.readline()
    String = str(String)
    print String 

    for case in switch(String):
        if case("Head"):
            print "test successed"
            break
        if case("Small"):
            print String
            break
        if case("Big"):
            print String
            break  
        if case():
            print String 
            break
```

the String value when I print it is Head, but the switch statement always goes to the last case.. the function works fine apparently because when I changed the String with v = "Head" it worked!!!

any idea what went wrong ?

the switch function -->

```
class switch(object):
 def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.fall = False

 def __iter__(self):
    """Return the match method once, then stop"""
    yield self.match
    raise StopIteration

 def match(self, *args):
    """Indicate whether or not to enter a case suite"""
    if self.fall or not args:
        return True
    elif self.value in args: # changed for v1.5, see below
        self.fall = True
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You should link the implementation of the `case` and `switch` objects/function, otherwise you are asking a question no one can answer.

Comment: Where did you take this `switch` function? Can you point to its source?

Comment: I added the implementation of the function

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? You're producing thoroughly unpythonic code. Be content with `if string == 'Head':`, `elif string == 'Small':`, etc.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - even better would be to use a dict :P

Comment: @detly: it depends. If it's a matter of calling a function based on that value, yes. If it's a matter of just a few statements (as his toy example is), certainly not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't ever write code like this. Do it in proper Python style. It's *much* easier to read. Anyone coming across usage of that "switch" mess will probably curse you heartily.

```
with open('/file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline().rstrip('\n')
    print line

if line == 'Head':
    print "test successed"
elif line == 'Small':
    print line
elif line == 'Big':
    print line
else:
    print line
```

---

As to why it's failing, the `readline()` call will very likely be including a trailing newline character, and `'Head' != 'Head\n'`.

Comment: Thanks, I would use the (line = fp.readline().rstrip('\n')) with the switch statement, I need the function to break and go out of the case when it finds the first comparison, because in my code I am comparing between lots of data .. I think if else statement goes through the whole list of if(s) and that won't be applicable to my need ... thank you again

Comment: @user573014: *it doesn't*. `if`, `elif`, `elif`, `elif`, `else`... it's handled efficiently. Which that `switch` thing is not - it's going to be *very* inefficient.

Comment: use fp.readline().rstrip() since line break could be "\r\n" so stripping \n will leave \r

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen: I was toying with adding `U` to the mode, but ended up being lazy. Probably not a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

`.readline()` returns the entire line, including the newline character.

You need to either `.strip()` your string, or compare to `'Head\n'` etc.

Also, regarding style, upper case variable names are not really a thing in python.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I am aware this is not Pythonic, but it was an interesting exercise.

This was before OP added the implementation -- here's my take.
It

- `raise`s with a meaningful error when there's no case defined -- or if `allow_fallthrough` is set, the default case can be handled with `for:else:`
- Allows the default case to occur wherever in the `"switch"` suite

.

```
def switch(arg, allow_fallthrough = False):
    fail = False
    def switcher(*args):
        return (arg in args)
    def default_switcher(*args):
        return (not args)
    def fallthrough(*args):
        if not allow_fallthrough:
            raise ValueError("switch(%r) fell through" % arg)
    yield switcher
    yield default_switcher
    yield fallthrough

def test():
    String = "Smallish"

    for case in switch(String):
        if case():
            print "default", String 
            break
        if case("Head"):
            print "Head GET"
            break
        if case("Small", "Smallish"):
            print "Small:", String
            break
        if case("Big"):
            print "Big:", String
            break  
    else: # Only ever reached with `allow_fallthrough`
        print "No case matched"
```